# Is this a sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space. For each open $U\subset X$ let $\mathcal{F}(U)$ be the ring of real functions on $U$ (not necessarily continuous). Is this a sheaf?

If $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is the ring of continuous functions from U to a topological space Y, this is a sheaf. But in the proof that this is a sheaf, where do we use continuity?

Comment: This is indeed a sheaf. You do not need continuity in the proof.

Comment: The moral is the following: A presheaf of functions with a certain property - say P - is a sheaf if and only if P can be checked locally. If we take all function, there is no property to be checked, so we clearly get a sheaf.

Comment: As an example, take the presheaf of bounded functions on a space $X$. This is not a sheaf in general, since boundedness can not be checked locally (for instance if $X=\mathbb R$. However if $X$ is compact, this is a sheaf, because on a compact space, boundedness can be checked locally on an open cover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the presheaf of all functions to $\Bbb R$ a sheaf. The glueing property of sheaves is clearly satisfied.

For the sheafiness of continuous functions, the key is to note that
a function $f:U\to Y$ is continuous iff it is locally continuous, that is
if for all $x\in U$ there is an open neighbourhood $V$ of $X$
where $V\subseteq U$ with $f|_V$ continuous. One can clearly always glue
a compatible family of continuous functions to make a locally continuous
function. As locally continuity implies continuity, that ensures that
the continuous functions form a sheaf.